# Django admin manytomany field

Tags: python, django

I'm a newbee to django and I'm trying to implement django models in django-admin.

Here is my models.py:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    salutation = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name


class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    website = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '    %s  ---->  %s' % (self.name, self.address)


class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    publication_date = models.DateField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

In this when I create a new book through the admin site it should allow me to select one or more authors, but instead all the authors are selected automatically and there is no option to remove any. There is a plus sign to add more authors but none to remove the authors already related.

I want to have the particular authors that I select for any particular book.

Comment: Offtopic: Make your class names singular and capitalised. members -> Member. Second do NOT make your own member object but use the build-in User model. Saving passwords like this is a BIG NO! Seriously, don't do it! ;)

Comment: The field names should be lowercase Author -> author. Even the code highlighting of SO gives you this hint.

Comment: yea.. ik.. i was just practicing....@allcaps

Comment: any solution to the problem??

Comment: Clean code helps people help you. Also help yourself. One day you read back your code and won't understand what goes wrong only to find out that you don't follow the convention. Also people are less likely to help. What do you expect them to do? Adhere the same sloppy style? Read PEP-8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: You can use `filter_horizontal` to create a more intuitive widget.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you have misunderstood how the widget works.
Here is an example of the use of Django's default widget for a ManyToManyField

Example: a teacher model is related to a language model:

```
teaching_languages = models.ManyToManyField('Language')
```

[image]

In the following case, English and Spanish are selected as values related to the teacher model, whilst French and German are not selected. 
The green + sign allows you to add another language to the teaching languages list.

Comment: Would it be possible to create an admin.TabularInline or admin.StackedInline for a manytomany field? I've been trying to but this seems to be the only widget available for a manytomany field.

Comment: You probably want a `filter_horizontal = ('teaching_languages',)` to allow the languages to be filtered, showing on the left the ones to select, and on the right the selected ones.